# Adding Links to SVG files

Tags: html, svg, hyperlink, path

Is there anyway to add hyperlinks to paths within SVG’s without having to do it in the HTML file. Since the SVG file is so massive it’s slowing down my HTML, so is there a way to add those links to the paths within the SVG file and then just refer to the SVG within the HTML so that it doesn’t slow the entire site down?

Comment: Like this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a#:~:text=The%20SVG%20element%20creates,but%20also%20around%20any%20shape.

Comment: Aside, if your svg is big, why not try optimising it with [svgomg](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/), which is a tool people use.

Answer (score 1):

detect the element or pixel you need to convert into a link and add the simple tag "a".

E.G.

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <a href="google.com">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Grettings.

Comment: Now is that in HTML or the SVG file?

Comment: in both cases, you can use svg file like HTML.

Comment: So I can add a link to my SVG and do it in my SVG file not embedded in HTML?

Comment: If you run it in a web browser it can be interpreted, if you open it in some other software I'm not sure